# How to pass variable to array data selector in jquery.each

Tags: jquery

I have this problem while trying do realtime chart with socket io

```
            window.Echo.channel('abc')
                .listen('xyz', (d) => {
                    $.each(chartOption.series, function (index, val) {
                        var name = val.name;
                        console.log(name);
                        val.data.shift();
                        val.data.push(d.name);
                    });
                });
```

So the problem is I wanna pass the val.name which can be various name (i1, i2, i3, .....) to the d."name" as the data selector which coming from socket io channel

I want on each chartOption.series
the data.push should push a diffirent data base on d.name
for example

```
d.i1
d.i2
d.i3
```

so how to pass the val.name into d. so it can get the correct data

Thank you

Comment: Can you please provide sample data for your input and result output which you are expecting? and what does "d" variable contains in terms of data.

Comment: for the d it is json data, for ex d {i1: 123, i2: 234, i3: 456}

Comment: for the val it is the series name where I want to put the data inside, for example
val.data(i1)
val.data(i2)

Comment: so I like to do the val.data.push(d.name) where name here could be i1, i2, i3 which take from val.name in $.each(chartOption.series, function (index, val) {

Comment: What is the chartOption.series data looks like?

Comment: chartOption.series for ex

{{
                            name: 'i1',
                            type: 'line',
                            data: {123,456,789},
                        }

Comment: if you are getting the name from this then why are you using d.name to push data into array? use the name variable

Comment: i found the way, just use d[name] is okay